# Create and apply a function that calculates the length of many strings in a vector

Tags: r, string, dataframe, lapply

Suppose I have a long vector with characters which is more or less like this:

```
vec <- c("32, 25", "5", "15, 24")
```

I want to apply a function which give me the number of strings for any element separated by a comma and returns me a vector with any individual length. Using `lapply` and my toy vector, this is my approach:

```
  lapply(vec, function(x) {
    a <- strsplit(x, ",")
    y <- length(a[[1:length(a)]])
    unlist(y[1:length(y)])
    })

[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2
```

This almost gives me what I want since first element has 2 strings, second element 1 string and third element 2 strings. The problem is I can't achieve that my function returns me a vector of the form `c(2,1,2).` I'm using this function to create a new variable on some `data.frame` which I'm working with.
Any idea will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `sapply` not `lapply` to get the vector you want.

Comment: Or use `unlist(lapply(vec, function(x) { a <- strsplit(x, ","); y <- length(a[[1:length(a)]]) }))`.

Comment: Also, there are dedicated functions for this sort of thing, e.g.: `count.fields(textConnection(vec), sep=",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
stringr::str_count(vec, ",") + 1
#> [1] 2 1 2
```

Or, in base R:

```r
nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", vec)) + 1
#> [1] 2 1 2
```